# Disadvantages to deleting default C++ copy and move constructors and assignment operators?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

If one has a class whose instances are never copied and never moved, are there any disadvantages to deleting the default move and copy constructors and assignment operators? This does fly directly against the rule of 0, but are there any other disadvantages (will the compiler generate suboptimal code, suboptimal data layout, etc)?

Comment: Is it in fact impossible to copy/move the class or are you expecting there will be no copy/move?

Comment: No it's just mildly annoying to deal with those classes but other than that they behave as you would expect.

Comment: If copying does not make sense for the type in question, then `=delete` copy operations. However, keeping move operations is usually a good idea. For example, it enables you to return them by value. Compare with `make_unique`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence or absence of a special member function has no effect on the data layout. Well, at least to the degree that the standard can guarantee such. That is, whether a class is standard layout (and therefore has a well-defined layout) has nothing to do with its constructors. It has only to do with its members. And if the class isn't standard layout... then the standard guarantees nothing.

In less theoretical terms however, there is absolutely no reason for the absence of a special constructor to impact the class's layout.

Obviously the standard has no way to enforce "optimal code" generation. But there is no real reason why the presence or absence of said members would result in the generation of worse code for the functions you do define.

Declaring a special member function as deleted should mean nothing besides causing a compilation failure whenever someone tries to call it.

Now, there are edge cases, but these are around how user code uses them. Namely, if you pass a reference to such a class to some template code that intends to move it around. But it can accept an immobile type, but it has to use a slower algorithm to do so(for some reason). It would use `std::is_move_constructible` to detect that the type isn't movable and use the slower algorithm.

> This does fly directly against the rule of 0

... so what? The rule is to use the default semantics unless your class needs other semantics. `unique_ptr` is conceptually a type where copying makes no sense, so it deletes the copy operations. If your type is conceptually a type where copying and moving make no sense, then you should delete those operations.

Note that "makes no sense" means that it is logically invalid, based on what your type is doing. A `unique_ptr`, *by definition*, uniquely owns an object. To copy the pointer would mean that it did not uniquely own the object. Since this would be logically invalid, the class cannot be copied.

If your class is conceptually immobile, then you should make it immobile in C++.

Answer (score 1):

> If one has a class whose instances are never copied and never moved,

This can mean one of two things:

1. Instances **must never** be copied or moved, because doing so would cause bad things such as shallow copying, or because it just doesn't make sense from a semantic point of view.
2. Instances just **don't currently happen** to be copied or moved.

> are there any disadvantages to deleting the default move and copy
>   constructors and assignment operators?

Depends on which of the two meanings is correct:

1. **No.** Quite the contrary; you should absolutely delete them to avoid accidental calls of the functions.
2. **Yes.** You will have to undo it later when the client code of your class changes and copying or moving will be needed. Or worse, client programmers may implement unnecessary and error-prone workarounds involving pointers to the instances, or manual copying by first extracting the data from the first instance and then building a new instance with the extracted data (imagine the chaos if `std::string` or `std::vector` were not copyable).

Answer (score 0):

There are no disadvantages. But there are no advantages either. It accomplishes absolutely nothing. The compiler will only generate default constructors or operators when they're needed. If they're not needed, whether they are officially deleted or not makes no difference whatsoever.

Now what does make a difference, is when you explicitly want to enforce that a class instance cannot be copied, assigned, etc. There are a myriad reason why some particular class may not be assignable, or move-constructed, etc. You can always define the appropriate constructor or operator, and throw an exception. But, in this case, you will discover that something is fubar-ed at runtime.

But, wouldn't you agree that it's much better, instead, to have the compiler enforce the no-move construction/assignment/whatever at compile-time, rather than runtime? Because if the constructor/operator is deleted, and somewhere a mistake is made, the compiler will immediately yell at you.